# How to store ParametricPlot in a variable without plotting the graph?

Tags: plotting, variable

Write separated commands for the following parametric equations using ParametricPlot and plot all of them in a single graph and show the combined graph only.

[image]

Comment: Put a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of each definition to suppress the display. See documentation for `CompoundExpression`

Comment: Please post your code instead of pictures.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bob Hanlon says in the comments you need to put in a ;

I think this is what you want

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{2 + 2 Cos[t], 2 + 2 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}];
p2 = ParametricPlot[{2 + Cos[t], 2 + Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}];
p3 = ParametricPlot[{1 + 0.1 Cos[t], 3 + 0.1 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}];
p4 = ParametricPlot[{3 + 0.1 Cos[t], 3 + 0.1 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

[image]

Note I had to retype your input. It is best if you use the formatting available in StackExchage so that you can paste and copy immediately into a notebook. You should be able to copy my version into your notebook. See use of {} in StackExchange toolbar. This is much easer for those of us trying to help you.

Comment: The separate plots can also be generated by `{p1, p2, p3, p4} = ParametricPlot[#, {t, 0, 2 Pi}] & /@ {{2 + 2 Cos[t], 2 + 2 Sin[t]}, {2 + Cos[t], 2 + Sin[t]}, {1 + 0.1 Cos[t], 3 + 0.1 Sin[t]}, {3 + 0.1 Cos[t], 3 + 0.1 Sin[t]}};`